# Spring Sending Message RAbbitMQ Rollback

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Hi I use spring rabbit to send message to rabbitmq.

I want to rollback sending message how can I do that ,my goal is to achive that in writing process.

Can anyone share code sample

Comment: You need to provide much more detail, including your existing code and configuration, and what you have tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask